# Save visio 2016 diagram in the vsd format programmatically

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visio, office-2016

I am migrating to Visio 2016 drawing control from Visio 2010. When I save a new file as .vsd outside the main Visio application it is throwing an exception. However, the file is saved on the given location. I save the file as .vsd for backward compatibility. This would affect reloading/opening the same new file and it is throwing an exception. Below snippet works well with Visio 2010.

```
BOOL Doc::SaveAs(vbPath)
{
    success = TRUE;

    if (!SUCCEEDED(CVisioDocument::SaveAsEx(vbPath, visSaveAsWS)))   //SaveAsEx return 0
    {
        success = FALSE;
    }

    // Now do a save to get the drawing on the Most Recently Used list
    short saveRc=0;
    if (!SUCCEEDED(CVisioDocument::Save(&saveRc)))  //Get exception here in Save method
        ASSERT(0);

    return success;
}
```

CVisioDocument::SaveAsEx(vbPath, visSaveAsWS) return "0". It means successfully saved new document.
But after I try, CVisioDocument::Save(&saveRc) throws an exception, because until a document has been saved, the Save method generates an error.
On the other hand, I can save a new document in the main Visio application without any exception. That's file is opening in the main Visio application.

So, Can you help with how can I get rid out of the above problem?

I find out someone has also a similar problem in Visio 2013, http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=4819.0

Comment: It's unlikely that you get an exception. The [Visio Drawing Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/visio/concepts/about-the-visio-drawing-control) is an ActiveX control. Its functionality is exposed through COM. Per COM rules, exceptions must not cross the ABI. So what's the real behavior you observe?

Comment: I caught exception in `catch(…)` that can be used to catch all types of exceptions. So did not specify what was the actual exception.
I observed that the above code snippet works well with Visio 2010. There was no exception while adding a new Visio document in a separate window to the same workspace to already opened main Visio the document.

Comment: What is the path you are saving to? Is it a valid path for saving a Visio file?

Comment: I am saving to C:\Users\Public\Documents where I also saved the first main .vsd document. We have practiced since Visio 2010. More, I have also tried to add the folder to the trusted location.
Yes, this is a valid path and have all the required permissions to access this location.